# Why didn't Jaime Lannister get this?

Tags: game-of-thrones

**SPOILERS FOR SEASON 3**

When Jaime loses his right hand, he has a gold prosthetic made. Then he has to re-learn how to fight using a sword in his left hand.

Why didn't Jaime get a prosthetic made that *includes* a sword/weapon of some kind? Like a prosthetic hand that is holding a sword, or a hook, or something more practical? Then he could have continued to use his right hand, or at least have an easier time re-learning how to fight. Something that he can switch to when he knows that he's going to fight.

Answers from books and/or shows are acceptable. (I personally have not read the books)

EDIT: Understandable that this is seen as opinion-based. I am not sure if there was some discussion of what to give Jaime for a "new hand" in the books or some spoken dialogue that I could have missed. Otherwise, I believe there *could* be a non primarily opinion-based answer (Mwr247's answer below) which makes sense, but I also believe Mwr answered part of the question (why not a sword) when there is still something I think could be answered.

Comment: Are you asking if his prosthetic hand should have a built-in sword or hook? Having a sword for a hand would be very awkward most times.

Comment: @RichS As per Mwr247 answer below, I understand why the sword (or something large) would be impractical, but how about a hook? Anything that could be more useful than a gold hunk.

Comment: @ZipZapJ I added a comment and edited my answer to expand on this.

Comment: This is directly explained in dialogue (so also, isn't "opinion based"!). Jaime complains that "a hook would be more practical" while Cersei (who oversaw it being made) says it's "elegant" and Qyburn praises the "exquisite" craftsmanship. It's designed to be a status symbol and a display of Lannister wealth and prestige, not an implement. Subtext:  they want Jaime to serve his house as a nobleman politician now, not a soldier, regardless of what he wants https://youtu.be/7QVQR020FFY

Comment: Regarding the close vote, I'm not sure how this question qualifies as "primarily opinion-based". There are lines from the show itself addressing why he gets the hand he does, as well as facts about prosthetics/physiology that explain why the alternatives (like a sword) would be a bad idea. It's a reasonable question to ask.

Comment: @user568458 Honestly, I have the exact same thing in mind. I've cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @user568458 Namely, *A Feast For Crows* Chapter 27 (Jaime III) addresses this, albeit lightly. Also, a good out-of-universe reason can be that GRRM wanted Jaime to bitch-slap Red Ronnet with his golden hand, that's #EpicAF!

Comment: Jaime still wouldn't have a wrist to move around. Jaime would be about as nimble with a sword as someone with their arm in a cast (or if you've ever tried to walk in ski boots, you should know how difficult it is to walk without a usable ankle; and walking is more natural to us than swordfighting).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A prosthetic hand will not be anywhere near as effective or versatile as a real one. Here are the different ranges of motion provided by the arm/wrist/fingers:

[image: It's all in the wrist... mostly...]

Considering he lost his hand from above the wrist, Jaime would be incapable of any of the degrees of motion detailed above (except supination/pronation, which would probably still be limited). These are essential in sword positioning for both attack and defense, and without them you would find yourself severely handicapped.

For example, how do you hold a sword up for a block, and then extend it for an attack? How would he rotate from the cutting edge to the side for a block? A low strike swinging in toward his right leg would be almost impossible to parry, because he could not angle the blade to protect from certain angles/blind spots.

Carrying the weight of a sword and absorbing blows would also be quite painful, not to mention how difficult it would be to affix a prosthetic to the arm that can handle all that pressure without breaking/tearing/coming off.

Even if it's not your dominant hand, you'll still be a more effective fighter using a real hand than a prosthetic.

EDIT:
As to why he wouldn't still opt to have a hook/small blade, the best we have for a definitive answer is from [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QVQR020FFY), where Cersei says she commissioned/designed it for him, and he remarks that a hook would be more practical. From this we can gather that while he might consider a hook if it were up to him, she's the one who made the choice, and he's decided he's ok with sticking with it. At the very least it's more visually appealing/impressive, and has been used practically to block, so maybe that's good enough for him.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to point this out, but I didn't think there'd be sufficient charts available.

Comment: That makes sense for not having a sword, but why not a hook or small blade (like Arya's Needle) that would be more useful than what he has (essentially nothing)?

Comment: @ZipZapJ [Per the show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QVQR020FFY), at least in part because he's not the one who made the decision (Cersei did), and he even points out that a hook would be more practical. A prosthetic made to look real is more visually appealing, for the same reason some people choose to put in glass eyes instead of wear an eyepatch (even if the eyepatch is more practical/comfortable).

Comment: As er the show, it has been shown in a training session with Bron that the prosthetic isn't firmly attached, and can be ripped off. I guess that's also part of the answer

Answer (score 1):

He still didn't have a *wrist*. So converting the stump into a weapon would still require him to learn how to fight again, plus it would look odd among the royalty.

Comment: The commander of the kings guard would look weird with a weapon as a hand? Also I mentioned that it would be something that Jaime could attach only when going to battle, not necessarily when hanging out around Cersei and the family.